# What's the difference between two capitalization styles related to acronym?

Tags: abbreviations, acronyms

I know NAT is the abbreviation of "**N**etwork **a**ddress **t**ranslation", but there is another style of this phrase, "**N**etwork **A**ddress **T**ranslation", which capitalize the first letter of each word.

What's the difference of these two styles, and which one is more appropriate?

From my observation, names like **B**ritish **B**roadcasting **C**orporation (BBC) are using the first style (capitalized with first letter of each word) in all circumstances. Does it mean phrases can be used in both styles but names can not?

Comment: Words in abbreviations like NAT need not be capitalized unless the abbreviation is an official name (FIFA, BBC) or a proper noun (UK, UN). Another example that doesn't need capitalization is GUI (graphical user interface).

Comment: @Justin In rare cases an abbreviation can evolve into a word in its own right and can be written as such with neither capitals nor stops.  The word 'snafu' is an example.  Or was.

Comment: @Tuffy - Agreed. Words like *scuba* and *laser* as well.

Comment: @Justin Thanks, that is exactly what I need.